# submit a form with ajax and js

Tags: javascript, ajax

so i tried to "parse" the form object with js and pass stuff that was supposed to be used to URL and submit a form with ajax.the code did not work.both A and B parameters were not successfully passed to server and response as i thought at the first place.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxForm(form){
 form = document.getElementById(form);
 var elements = form.elements;
 var content="";
 var element;
 for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
  element = elements[i];
  if(element.type=="text"){
     content += encodeURIComponent(element.name)+"="+encodeURIComponent(element.value)+"&";
     }
  }
  ajaxSubmit(content);
 }
function ajaxSubmit(content){
    if(content.length==0){
    document.getElementById("txtinput").innerHTML="";
}
if(windows.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("txtinput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?"+content,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="ajax_form">
 A:<input type="text" name="A" />
<br/>
 B:<input type="text" name="B" />
<input type="submit" onsubmit="ajaxForm('ajax_form')" />
</form>
<p>Elevator:<span id="txtinput" ></span><br/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php:

```
<?php 
 $response = "This is simply an example for debugging purposes";
 echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Did just a quick test and can see that A and B were passed.

Comment: yeah if A and B were passed "this is..." thing would show up beside "Elevator:".in terms of not working i mean both A and B were not actually passed so it stayed at index page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AjaxForm and AjaxSubmit are never getting called, instead the form is getting submitted in the normal way. You need something like

```
<form id="ajax_form" onsubmit="ajaxForm('ajax_form');return false;">
```

Comment: i tried to add an URL parameter in ajaxSubmit:ajaxSubmit(url,method,content),then at the end of ajaxForm i have ajaxSubmit(form.action,form.method,content),then <form action="process.php" method="get"> .however it redirects to process.php instead of what ajax would do

Answer (score 0):

try changing encodeURLComponent to ecodeURIComponent

Comment: did that solve your problem? If not try doing a console log of your content to ensure it is being properly encoded.